# Generated with maven war file missed some jars

Tags: maven-3

I generate .war file with maven and one jar is missed at the end. As a result my app doesn't even start. When I add missed jar to unpacked war under tomcat everything starts working correctly.

Here is a pom.xml that contains dependencies I need:

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
  <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
  <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
  <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
  <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.allen-sauer.gwt.log</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-log</artifactId>
  <version>${google.gwt-log.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.gwt-widget</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-sl</artifactId>
  <version>${google.gwt-sl.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
 </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

It seems everything is correct, but at the end vaadin-server.jar is present and vaadin-client.jar is absent. What is wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding the runtime scope for vaadin-client?

Like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
  <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
  <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried runtime but the result is the same. I even had an idea to add provided scope and put vaadin-client under tomcat, but I think it isn't as good as it may seem :)

Comment: Can you try removing vaadin-server dependecy? I created a test project and I saw that vaadin-client already includes it

Comment: Yes, I tried. Vaadin-server is in war and vaadin-client still not :(

Comment: I found the source of problem. Someone added vaadin-client-* to <war.packaging.excludes>. That's why it wasn't added. Wierd joke, I may say.
Anyway thanks for pointing on indirect dependency to vaadin-server in vaadin-client.